# Eclipselink : Operation not supported: [instantiateForUnitOfWorkValueHolder]

Tags: eclipselink, lazy-loading, jpa-2.0

I get the following error when I try to access Lazy loaded @oneToMany relationship attribute in a method present in Entity.

**Error:**

```
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-7097] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.3.v20160428-59c81c5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: Operation not supported: [instantiateForUnitOfWorkValueHolder].
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException.operationNotSupported(ValidationException.java:1496)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.indirection.ProtectedValueHolder.instantiateForUnitOfWorkValueHolder(ProtectedValueHolder.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.indirection.UnitOfWorkValueHolder.instantiateImpl(UnitOfWorkValueHolder.java:160)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.indirection.UnitOfWorkValueHolder.instantiate(UnitOfWorkValueHolder.java:234)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.indirection.DatabaseValueHolder.getValue(DatabaseValueHolder.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.indirection.IndirectList.buildDelegate(IndirectList.java:271)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.indirection.IndirectList.getDelegate(IndirectList.java:455)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.indirection.IndirectList$1.<init>(IndirectList.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.indirection.IndirectList.listIterator(IndirectList.java:596)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.indirection.IndirectList.iterator(IndirectList.java:555)
    at com.order.modelGroupBase.getStatus(GroupBase.java:205)
```

**Entity:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="GROUP")
@Customizer(GroupBaseCustomizer.class)
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@ClassExtractor(GroupClassExtractor.class)
@InstantiationCopyPolicy
@Cacheable
@Cache( alwaysRefresh=true,
refreshOnlyIfNewer=true,
expiry=300000,      
coordinationType = CacheCoordinationType.SEND_NEW_OBJECTS_WITH_CHANGES)
public class GroupBase {

@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="groupBase", targetEntity=Groups.class)
@PrivateOwned
private List groups = new ArrayList<>();

public OrderGroupStatus getStatus() {

//error is at this line when I try to iterate..
for (Iterator itr = getGroups().iterator(); itr.hasNext();) {
    Groups relationship = (Groups) itr.next();
    //some operation..

    }           


}

}
```

I've looked upon in eclipselink forum but they don't address this issue explicitly and some links say it's related to weaving.But in my application I haven't enabled weaving at all and I also don't intend to do.

This code works fine on Eclipselink 2.3.2 without JPA. Now I'm using Eclipselink 2.6.3 with JPA 2.0 and IBM Websphere 8.5.5.8.

**Note:** This issue occurs randomly not every time and also when ever a new object is created is what I have observed.

Comment: Weaving might have been mentioned as it is required for lazy fetching of 1:1 and other performance optimizations.  I'd look into using it unless you have a strong reason not to.  In this case though, weaving isn't needed for lazy fetching of 1:m and M:M as EclipseLink can inject its own list implementation.  I've not seen this error before, but the quick workaround (not recommended) is to mark the mapping as eager (collections are lazy by default).  It must have something to do with your cache settings, disallowing the fetch on the GroupBase relationship.  how was GroupBase  read in.

Comment: Also, what was 'working' in 2.3.2 if you are now using JPA?  Did you just do a straight 1:1 conversion to setting JPA annotations to prior EclipseLink settings?  If you use the old, non-JPA code 'as is' with the new EL library does it work?  What does Groups look like, and what is logged if you put logging on Finest?

Comment: Hi @Chris Thanks for looking into the issue ! In 2.3.2 the iteration over lazy loaded list worked fine means no exception thrown ever.When I converted to JPA annotations and upgraded to 2.6.3 I face this issue in the iteration of lazy loaded list. I have not used and ASIS old code I have converted normal pojo classes to entities. Logging​ doesn't show anything interesting it just prints this stack trace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many hit and trails and correcting my lazy loading settings, I've found out that using different fetchType on same entity in other entities can cause this issue in SHARED_CACHE mode.

```
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="groupBase", targetEntity=Groups.class)
@PrivateOwned
private List groups = new ArrayList<>();
```

By default @OneToMany is lazily fetched but in another entity for the same entity 'Groups' I had configured fetchType as EAGER.

When I made both fetch types to LAZY this error stopped occurring.